# Select stored procedure names by comment in Mysql

Tags: mysql, select, stored-procedures

How can I get stored procedure names by comment in Mysql?

For example I need something like this:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM stored_procedures
    WHERE comment LIKE '%something%''
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the stored procedure name from `information_schema` using below code:

```
SELECT routine_schema,      -- database/schema wherein the object resides
       routine_name,        -- the name of the function/procedure
       routine_type,        -- PROCEDURE indicates a procedure, FUNCTION indicates a function
       routine_definition   -- code underlying the sp
       routine_comment      -- some human readable comment on the routine
  FROM information_schema.routines
  WHERE routine_comment LIKE '%test%';
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can search proc by comments like this..

```
SELECT mysql.proc.name
FROM mysql.proc
WHERE mysql.proc.comment LIKE '%abc%';
```

Comment: Is this a SQLSERVER answer?

Comment: It doesn't syntax in mysql ERROR 1109 (42S02): Unknown table 'proc' in information_schema

Comment: It works now that you have edited it to include mysql, though it does probably need to be qualified by.